# How to plot coordinates with different colors on a map?

Tags: plotting, graphics, map

How can I plot different sets of coordinates with different colors? For example, the two maps below would be merged into one map, with two colors. 
I'm using the commands below to create the maps below - the coordinates are comma-separated and stored in input files.

```
latlong = Import["cluster0.txt", "CSV"];

Graphics[{Gray,  Polygon[Map[GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[#], "Mercator"][[1]] &, CountryData["United States", "Coordinates"], {2}]], Red,  PointSize[.01], Point /@ Map[ GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[#], "Mercator"][[1]] &, {latlong}, {2}]}]

latlong2 = Import["cluster2.txt", "CSV"];

Graphics[{Gray,  Polygon[Map[GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[#], "Mercator"][[1]] &, CountryData["United States", "Coordinates"], {2}]], Green,  PointSize[.01], Point /@ Map[ GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[#], "Mercator"][[1]] &, {latlong2}, {2}]}]
```

[image]

[image]

(Update:) I am using *Mathematica* version 8 so I would prefer solutions that work with this version.

Comment: Please show the code you have so far.

Comment: Do you have geo coordinates for points?

Comment: I have edited my question with the commands that I used. I have a lot of coordinates and they are stored in input files.

Comment: So you just add `Green,  PointSize[.01], Point /@...` to your first `Graphics` call, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

```
continentalcities = CityData[{Large, "UnitedStates"}] /. {_, "Alaska" | "Hawaii", _} :> 
    Sequence[];
coords = Map[GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[#], 
      "Mercator"][[1]]&, {CityData[#, "Coordinates"] & /@ continentalcities}, {2}];
statestocolors = Thread[CountryData["UnitedStates", "Regions"] -> 
         ColorData["GeologicAges", "ColorList"][[;; 51]]];
coordsandcolors = Transpose[{coords[[1]], continentalcities, 
         continentalcities[[All, 2]] /. statestocolors}];

Graphics[{Gray, Polygon[Map[GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[#], "Mercator"][[1]] &, 
    CountryData["UnitedStates", "Coordinates"], {2}]], 
    PointSize[.01], {#3, Tooltip[Point[#1], #2]} & @@@ coordsandcolors}]
```

[image]

For your datasets `latlong` and `latlong2`, as noted by @BlacKow already, you can use

```
Graphics[{Gray, Polygon[Map[GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[#], "Mercator"][[1]] &, 
    CountryData["United States", "Coordinates"], {2}]], PointSize[.01],
     Green, Point /@ Map[GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[#], 
       "Mercator"][[1]] &, {latlong2}, {2}], 
     Red, Point /@ Map[GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[#], 
       "Mercator"][[1]] &, {latlong}, {2}]}]
```

Comment: It worked fantastic!!!

Comment: @kglr nice sample data :)

Comment: Now it's even better! Is it Friday already?

Comment: thank you @BlacKow. Scrolled the page too fast to notice that you already answered Thiago's specific question:)

Answer (score 3):

```
set1 = {{38.9, -77.03}, {38.9, -87.03}};
set2 =  {{36.9, -77.03}, {33.9, -87.03}};

Graphics[#, AspectRatio -> 0.65] &@{Gray,CountryData["USA", "Polygon"], Pink, PointSize[0.01], 
Point[GeoPosition[set1]], Green, Point[GeoPosition[set2]]}
```

[image]

I'm not sure about aspect ratio...
I cannot check MMA 8.0, but this should work for you

```
Graphics[{Gray, 
  Polygon[Map[GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[#], "Mercator"][[1]] &, 
    CountryData["United States", "Coordinates"], {2}]], Green, 
  PointSize[.01], 
  Point /@ Map[
    GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[#], "Mercator"][[1]] &, {set2}, {2}], 
  Pink, Point /@ 
   Map[GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[#], 
       "Mercator"][[1]] &, {set1}, {2}]}]
```

Or the following will probably work too:

```
Graphics[#, AspectRatio -> 0.65] &@{Gray, 
  CountryData["USA", "Polygon"], Pink, PointSize[0.01], 
  Point[GeoPosition /@ set1], Green, Point[GeoPosition /@ set2]}
```

Comment: I'm using Mathematica 8 and your command is returning this error: Coordinate GeoPosition[{{38.9, -77.03}, {38.9, -87.03}}] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Your 2nd command works fine on Mathematica 8, but the last code snippet doesn't work. Thank you.